# Startup transient on LMR14030-Q1 buck converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck

So I'm trying to build my first buck converter for an audio project using a [TI LMR14030-Q1](https://www.ti.com/product/LMR14030-Q1). My first design had some acoustic noise so I changed the switching frequency, inductor, and output capacitors, which fixed that problem. Here's the current design generated using TI Webench ([design](https://webench.ti.com/appinfo/webench/scripts/SDP.cgi?ID=6A9531E9A4BBD4FF)):

[image: Buck converter schematic]

[Full project schematics & PCB layout](https://oshwlab.com/c904/i2s-amp-with-aux-in)

Now the problem is it's blowing my amp chip, an [Infineon MA12070](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/power/class-d-audio-amplifier-ic/integrated-class-d-audio-amplifier-ics/ma12070/), on startup. I didn't catch it in action on the oscilloscope, but with the dead amp chip removed this is what I see on startup:

Channel 1 (yellow) = Vin, Channel 2 (blue) = Vout

[image: Startup oscilloscope screenshot with Vin and Vout]

Any thoughts on what might be causing the large dip in Vout before it gets back to 5V and how to prevent that?

Also am I right in thinking that's probably what's breaking my amp chip since Vin looks fine? The absolute maximum System supply voltage for the chip is 6V and it looks like it's peaking around 5.76V, so I don't think it's the peak necessarily that's the problem. The chip has an /ENABLE pin that I've tied to Vout with a pull-up resistor, so when Vout dips like that it enables the amp briefly, and since things aren't stable yet I'm thinking that may be breaking it. Or else maybe there's an inrush current issue? Not sure how to check for that without a zero-ohm resistor somewhere to watch on the oscilloscope.

FWIW, here's the startup simulation from TI Webench, which is missing that initial spike:

[image: Startup simulation]

And here's a view on the oscilloscope that includes the SW pin of the LMR14030-Q1:

Channel 1 (yellow) = Vsw, Channel 2 (blue) = Vout

[image: Startup oscilloscope screenshot with Vsw and Vout]

And a zoom in on the steady state of Vsw on the oscilloscope, in case that helps:

[image: Vsw steady state oscilloscope screenshot]

---

**Update**: Closer view of Vin and Vout:

[image: Vin to Vout oscilloscope screenshot]

---

**2nd Update**: [Actual PCB layout](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZOPSGwHxAzFy0gSPnJK05vB5-RogH2jO/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Are you 100% certain that this is not just a measurement error? It can be a bit tricky to probe what happens at the moment of plugging things in, as there is inadvertently a large dv/dt spike which easily couples into the oscilloscope probe. If you haven't done so, try probing with a ground spring directly across one of the output caps instead of using the long (antenna) ground lead.

Comment: Why are you using a switching regulator for the analogue low level auxiliary supply?

Comment: It looks like you have some transient leakage path from Vin to Vout.  You can see Vout rising before the switch even starts switching and before the soft-start period begins.

Comment: The output capacitors look polarised - are they aluminium or tantalum? What's the ESR?

Comment: @Klas-Kenny Good point -- I don't have a ground spring at the moment, but if I can't figure out what's going on I'll definitely give that a try.

Comment: @Andyaka Good question -- I was worried about the heat loss from a linear regulator going from 19V to 5V. Maybe I shouldn't have been? I do have separate, low noise linear regulators coming off the switched 5V going into the DAC and Volume IC, but the reference design in the amp's datasheet had the digital and analog 5V coming from the same source so I figured it would be alright, especially since this is just a DIY project.

Comment: @raaymaan Yes, I went with Panasonic 10TPE47MAZB Conductive Polymer Tantalum Solid Capacitors: 47 uF +/- 20 %, 10 VDC, ESR: 35 mOhms (https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Panasonic/10TPE47MAZB?qs=OE1iw1LrrPFA5jtx2CbXHA%3D%3D ). This was one of the things I switched from the original design's MLCCs to try to reduce acoustic noise. Those were https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Samsung-Electro-Mechanics/CL32B476KPJNNWE?qs=sGAEpiMZZMuMW9TJLBQkXhJr1djrFpnnGLGBdScbjlU%3D

Comment: @JohnD Interesting! I added a closer view on the oscilloscope and that definitely looks to be the case. Any way to solve that besides adding distance between Vin and Vout on the PCB?

Comment: 1) I know it was presented in the design from webench, but there is no mention of including the 470p feed-forward capacitor in the datasheet or in the evaluation kit user guide (LMR14030SEVM)

Comment: 2) I see your IC U2 has the DDA suffix, I wondered if this was true and you are actually using SO-Power Pad case, not the WSON. The datasheet states: "For LMR14030-Q1 in WSON package, the maximum value of CSS is 4.7 nF"

Comment: @CletusW I'd start troubleshooting by completely isolating the buck, maybe if you have a spare PCB just build up the buck circuit on it.  Test that, then start adding additional components until the problem occurs.  Or analyze the circuit for any path between Vin and Vout that doesn't involve the buck converter.  If the buck isn't switching Vout shouldn't be rising like it does.

Comment: Whoops, just noticed I had uploaded an old PCB screenshot. Updated now.

@raaymaan 1) Good point, I was wondering why they included that. I removed it and nothing seems to have changed, which I guess is nice to know regardless!

2) Yes, I'm using the 8 pin PowerPad package, not the WSON.

Comment: @JohnD I do have some spare PCBs -- that makes total sense. I'll give it a try, thanks!

Comment: So I just assembled the buck alone on a spare PCB and am getting the same issue. I also tried swapping back to the non-polarized output capacitors (MLCC instead of solid polymer tantalum) and that didn't help. I guess I need to try a different diode next? I'd post on TI's forums but it's not letting me for some reason.

Comment: TI recommended an RC delay circuit on the enable pin. That seems to help when connecting power via a wire on a breadboard, but if I instead turn it on by plugging in the DC adapter jack, it still has a spike (albeit a shorter one). Maybe the jack is sparking? Are there better ones that connect more smoothly? Or something external to the jack I can add to reduce the spike?

Comment: The problem may be outside the viewport of the layout shown. Cany you provide a larger viewport and separate pictures of the copper layers? A large cap between VIn and VOut would produce signals like we see here.

Comment: @jens Here's screenshots of the full PCB layout: Top: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZOPSGwHxAzFy0gSPnJK05vB5-RogH2jO/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @jens Bottom: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q1XOfXd4J3naaDiMMyZP2148BfCq2tVg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @jens The regulator chip & amp chip connect to Vin & Vout (+5V), so there could be leakage there (still talking with TI support about that). There are no capacitors between the two. I suppose there could be accidental coupling between them since there are two places where the traces get quite close? (This is my first PCB of this complexity and routing was tricky).

Comment: @CletusW: Looks all nice and clean, could not find a problem there..

Comment: @Jens Okay, thanks for taking a look.

Comment: @CletusW: I find this very interesting because it's so absurd. Please post the solution when you finally find the virtual 100uF between VIn and VOut